# Best things to unit test in EpiServer CMS

Tags: unit-testing, content-management-system, tdd, episerver

I know off the bat this a loaded question and there are probably tons of ideas, but I'm having a tough time online finding examples of the things that are typical to unit test in EPIServer.

I think a good start is if anyone had experience doing unit testing and TDD in a test environment, that will probably get us somewhere.  I'm not familiar with CMS sort of unit testing with blocks and page types etc.. so I'm trying to get some guidance.

Thank you

Comment: In most cases, my best bet was to leave EPiServer infrastructure out of any kind of customer logic. You develop it simply using .NET Framework and only utilise the results in EPiServer specific objects. That way you are free to Unit Test whichever part of logic you choose, the same way as if it was a non CMS application.  
  
In TDD :   
1. See what you have on input  
2. Check what EPiServer element needs  
3. Write a test taking input and returning expected result  
4. Tests pases, you have your logic in place.   
  
Testing EPiServer internals is just a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical example would be things you're fetching using `IContentLoader`.
Let's say you use the following code to fetch the main menu items:

```
var items = _contentLoader.GetChildren<PageData>(ContentReference.StartPage)
            ... // filtering
            .ToList();
```

You obviously need to filter out container pages, restricted pages, unpublished pages, pages that have `VisibleInMenu` set to `False`, etc.

To unit test that, you would need to mock `IServiceLocator`, `IContentLoader`, `ITemplateResolver`, `IPublishedStateAssessor`, etc.

I haven't found any open source mocking/testing framework for Episerver other then https://github.com/DavidVujic/EPiServer-FakeMaker

Most companies that are unit testing Episerver solutions have developed their own frameworks, which are not publically available. David's FakeMaker is a good start.